# Can I use "came by" in the past tense?

Tags: past-tense, american-english

I want to write that I ran to the bus stop because I wanted to be at the bus stop before the bus came. But later I realized that I had missed the bus.

I am trying to write it in simple words. Is this correct sentence?

> I was a little late.
>   So I ran to get to the bus stop before the bus came by.
>   After waiting for long time, I realized that I had missed the bus.

Does "bus came by" mean the bus actually came? But the bus never really came.
Or should I write "So I ran to get to the bus stop before the bus arrived"?

Answer (score 1):

In colloquial English, it is "So I ran to get to the bus stop before the bus *arrived*." *Ran* is past tense, so the *arrival is also in the past*. If you are writing in the *present*, it is "So I *run* to get to the bus stop before the bus *arrives*."

Comment: So, yes, your original phrasing was correct.  "came by" is just as good as "arrived".  And it's good to ask, because this is odd use of simple past for "counterfactual" (something didn't happen.) The important thing is that when you were running, at that time, IN YOUR MIND, the bus was going to come.

Answer (score -1):

I would say:

> So I ran to get to the bus stop before the bus **arrives**.

I would not use past tense here, since your intended action is in the present tense.
In the last sentence, the result is known. Then past tense is fine.